# How to random button on JPanel for game Sliding puzzle?

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, jpanel, jbutton

Today i has created game Sliding Puzzle using java in IDE Netbean . i also created it with 3 * 3 row and col picture for set image on button. i can only create button sequence of index in jpanel . how can i random position button  with image but make sure that it remember position in panel of picture matched. and how can i know it win? if my info is not enough please ask me more.

```
     position = new int[row][col];
            lstBtn = new JButton[row][col];
            count = new int[row * col];
            panelContainer.setLayout(null);
            panelContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
            BufferedImage img;
            int numCount = 0;
            int posNum=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {


 for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {

                position[i][j] = posNum++;

                if (i == 0 & j == 0) {
                    lstBtn[i][j] = new JButton();
                    lstBtn[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    lstBtn[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);
                    panelContainer.add(lstBtn[i][j], numCount);
                    count[0] = numCount;
                } else {
                      numCount++;

                    lstBtn[i][j] = new JButton();
                    lstBtn[i][j].addActionListener(this);

                //   img = image_cutting.getSubImage(j,i);//160, 116 //120, 87,
                //  lstBtn[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(160, 116, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
                    lstBtn[i][j].setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                    lstBtn[i][j].setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
                    lstBtn[i][j].setFont(new Font("Dialog",2,20));
                    lstBtn[i][j].setForeground(Color.BLUE);

                    lstBtn[i][j].setText("" + numCount);

                    panelContainer.add(lstBtn[i][j], numCount);
                    lstBtn[i][j].setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println(numCount);
                }
                if (numCount == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                count[numCount] = numCount;
            }
        }
```

Comment: so you are asking how to give a button a random position? please clarify your question.

Comment: yes i want jbutton random position

Comment: Create your own Buttonobject/Panelobject which contains a panel, current position, original position. Set all Objects to the original position (one position is empty, you might want this also as Object with a null-button, depending on your preferred design). To ensure you can win, just make several legit random moves. To check, if you won, compare every position with original position.

Comment: so maybe it far from what i do now.

Comment: do you know how to generate random numbers in java?

Comment: you could get a random number between 0 and 2 using `Random ran = new Random(); int x = ran.next(2);` and then another one `int y = ran.next(2);` then set the component to the grid square corresponding to `x` and `y`

Comment: @ctst: you are correct, my bad. I will delete my suggestion, and thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @ epicTCK : you meant i should set x, y on square grid.